# Convert one column of numbers on excel into multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I need to Convert one large column on windows excel 2016 of numbers into multiple columns of 10 rows each.

I am currently doing this manually. Please help me Stackoverflow! :)

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
```

The results should be this:

```
1           11
2           12
3           13
4           14
5           15
6           16
7           17
8           18
9           19
10          20
```

and so on....

Comment: Are you interested a piece of VBA code?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,ROW()+((COLUMN(A1)-1)*10))
```

Drag right and 10 down.